# word-wrap: break-word with div inside td

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, word-wrap

I'm trying to use the CSS word-wrap property with break-word value.
I want to use this inside a td, and apparently need to use a additional div tag for this to work. fine.

I tried to build a simplified use-case:

**HTML:**

```
<table class="sectors">
  <tr>
    <td><div>HURTEAUX / Jean-Baptiste mr)</div></td>
    <td><div>CHEUNJGgdfgdfvfsefsdfsdfsdfsdvvvHJG / Samuel mr</div></td>
    <td><div>CHEUNG / Samuel mr)</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.sectors td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.sectors td div {
  width: 150px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

### **The problem**

Firefox, Chrome and Safari behave as expected (at least as I expect).

[screenshot on Firefox 3.5](http://screencast.com/t/xyRv0Ah6)

But IE (IE6, IE7, IE8) has a strange behavior: the text is properly wrapped inside the div (red border), but it seems the td (black border) is allocating extra space for no reason.

[screenshot on IE7](http://screencast.com/t/sQ9VvsEqpa)

Any workaround or explanation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding overflow:hidden to the div should sort it out. Can't offer an explanation though, sorry!